# Grep - не желает много работать

Tags: linux, grep

Добрый день. В Linux е я жутко зеленый новичок, прошу помочь. Разбираюсь в платформе сайта, сделанного для меня программистом, с которым давно поссорился. Ищу компонент с помощью grep,  по типу

```
grep -rlis "test" / >>/grepresult.txt
```

Он зависает, написав несколько десятков строк, или 4096 байт кода. При этом putty рвет соединение. :(

Что я делаю не так?

Самое интересное, какой-то из вариаций я положил сервер. Ну, как сервер Nginx помер, ребут не помогает (раньше nginx запускался). Надо чинить автозапуск. Как бы узнать, с чего он сломался?
Может, чует во мне юзверя?

Comment: нужно найти какой-то текст в куче файлов?

Comment: Да. Разбираюсь, как работает компонент сайта, хочу найти все места, где мелькает его название. Я просто подумал, что почему бы и не греп? Спросил пару людей, как-то grep не любят. Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуй для такой цели (обойти все и искать текст в файлах) я бы запустил:

```
 find / -type f -exec grep -lis "искомый текст или регэксп" '{}' \;
```

от рута.

(-type f означает, что grep будет вызываться только для обычных файлов (не сокеты, устройства, FIFO и т.п.))

Comment: не нужно запускать grep под рутом, если не понимаешь, как оно работает. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что ТС это нужно. 146%, что ему нужно грепать `/var/www` и домашний каталог.

Если код работает под апачем (максимум - под nginx), то нужно просто посмотреть в конфиг апача, выяснить каталог и дальше уже смотреть.

Comment: а куда в данной функции можно поставить >>/grepresult.txt, чтобы сделать вывод в файл? а то я ставил на паузу, а файл пуст. пробовал
find / -type f -exec grep -lis "Payment" '{}' \; >> grepresult.txt
find / -type f -exec grep -lis "Payment" >>grepresult.txt '{}' \;

Comment: @ENexus, 

    find / -type f -exec grep -lis "Payment" '{}' \; >> grepresult.txt

это правильно (если хотите добавлять новый вывод  к старому содержимому).

В `grepresult.txt` после завершения find будут имена файлов.

Comment: @ENexus, `>> file` это дописать в конец файла, а `> file` записать в файл, удалив предыдущее содержимое.

В целом, в shell `;` это разделитель команд. Но в данном случае 
`\;`  (`;` не зря заэкранирована символом `\`) относится к аргументам find и означает конец аргументов grep, которую find вызывает для каждого файла. 

А  на место `{}` find  при вызове grep подставит имя файла. Я заключаю `{}` в апострофы "на всякий случай", поскольку, смутно помнится, в каком-то из shell-ов эти символы имели спциальное значение.

Смотреть результаты по мере вывода можно командой `tail -f file` в др. окне.

Comment: А, точно, обратный слэш. понял. появился кстати файл grepresult.txt, (с запятой на конце) , тоже пустой. и через команду top процесс find отображается как спящий, а grep - остановленный. Может, что-то не так сделал? Консоль висит, сообщений не выдавала. Ось CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
30653 root      20   0  100m  840  704 T  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 grep
28260 root      20   0  109m 1236  900 S  0.0  0.0   0:11.34 find

Comment: Непонятно... (думаю набиваете не те буковки).

--

Для начала проверьте -- обходит ли успешно find все

    find / -name a 

Если зависнет -- создавайте новый вопрос с детальным описанием (тут уже места мало для "исследований").

Потом сделайте в /tmp файл f с текстом XXX (echo XXX >/tmp/f)
 и запустите Ваш find в /tmp (find /tmp ....) для поиска файлов с XXX и записью их имен в `/tmp/grepresult.txt`.

Если пройдет, запустите эту же строчку, заменив /tmp на / и с grep-ом на "что Вы ищете" и когда зависнет сделайте

    ps -ef | grep grep ; ps -ef | grep find

и пришлите вывод.

Comment: [root@CentOS-64-64-minimal ~]# ps -ef | grep grep ; ps -ef | grep find

root      1922 13460  1 13:45 pts/0    00:00:10 find / -type f -exec grep -lis Payment {} ;

root     18638  1922  0 13:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -lis Payment /proc/kmsg

root     18797  5120  0 14:01 pts/1    00:00:00 grep grep

root      1922 13460  1 13:45 pts/0    00:00:10 find / -type f -exec grep -lis Payment {} ;

root     18799  5120  0 14:01 pts/1    00:00:00 grep find

[root@CentOS-64-64-minimal ~]#

(серверное время на 2 часа меньше)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить к grep --exclude='/proc/*' т.е. получим

    find / -type f -exec grep --exclude='/proc/*' -lis Payment '{}' \; >/tmp/grepresult.txt

В /proc явно не м.б. интересующих Вас файлов. 

Про зависание grep

    /proc/kmsg. This file is used to hold messages generated by the kernel.

т.е. grep просто бесконечно ждет поступления данных.

(извините, совсем забыл о подобных файлах в /proc (при работе от root)).

Comment: Он все-таки дошёл до конца. Спасибо за помощь! 
[root@CentOS-64-64-minimal /]# find / -type f -exec grep --exclude='/proc/*' -lis Payment '{}' \; >/tmp/grepresult.txt


find: `/proc/20060/task/20060/fd/5': No such file or directory

find: `/proc/20060/task/20060/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory

find: `/proc/20060/fd/5': No such file or directory

find: `/proc/20060/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory

[root@CentOS-64-64-minimal /]#

Итого grepresult.txt 36039 байт

Answer (score 0):

В качестве начальной папки Вы указываете корень. А это значит, что искать будет **ВЕЗДЕ**. А заходите Вы, скорее всего, обычным пользователем. А его много куда и не пустит.

Но некоторые файлы в линукс не совсем файлы, и чтение их может привести к разным результатам.

Рекомендую явно указывать точный каталог, где искать.

запуск grep может нагрузить систему, особенно, если их запустить много (нагрузка на файловую систему и процессор).

А вот как угробили nginx - кто его знает. Может быть, Вы ещё что-то запускали?

Comment: Нет, захожу под рутом. Да, знаю, что не рекомендуется. Стараюсь не поломать, уже сломал. Может, поиск в каких-то папках запрещен или невозможен? Хотя вроде стоит опция -s, игнорировать нечитаемые файлы и ошибки.
Запускал греп и его различные вариации, типа grep, grep --help, один раз забыл указать текст. По времени отрезанных логов подходит только grep. Я как раз перед сном искал (до этого ничего не делал), с рассчетом, что искать будет долго, и попытался запустить несколько раз.

Comment: при этом putty подвисал, или давал фатальную ошибку, в логе Network error: Software caused connection abort. и некоторое время не давал подсоединиться

Comment: Может, какой-нибудь /dev/zero читает и там какое-нибудь переполнение происходит, хотя скорее всего там защита от дурака есть.

Comment: @deterok, проверил сейчас на Ubuntu 14.04. Никакой защиты нет, что ожидаемо. "grep asdf /dev/zero" честно пожирает всю доступную память. Похоже, у автора проблема именно в этом.

Comment: очень похоже на правду. там есть ещё всякие `/dev/random` и `/dev/urandom`, которые даже могут иметь совпадающий текст.